# Loading CSV into dataframe results in all records becoming "NaN"

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm new to python (and posting on SO), and I'm trying to use some code I wrote that worked in another similar context to import data from a file into a MySQL table. To do that, I need to convert it to a dataframe. In this particular instance I'm using Federal Election Comission data that is pipe-delimited (It's the "Committee Master" data [here](https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data)). It looks like this.

C00000059|HALLMARK CARDS PAC|SARAH MOE|2501 MCGEE|MD #500|KANSAS CITY|MO|64108|U|Q|UNK|M|C||
C00000422|AMERICAN MEDICAL ASSOCIATION POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE|WALKER, KEVIN MR.|25 MASSACHUSETTS AVE, NW|SUITE 600|WASHINGTON|DC|200017400|B|Q||M|M|ALABAMA MEDICAL PAC|
C00000489|D R I V E POLITICAL FUND CHAPTER 886|JERRY SIMS JR|3528 W RENO||OKLAHOMA CITY|OK|73107|U|N||Q|L||
C00000547|KANSAS MEDICAL SOCIETY POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE|JERRY SLAUGHTER|623 SW 10TH AVE||TOPEKA|KS|666121627|U|Q|UNK|Q|M|KANSAS MEDICAL SOCIETY|
C00000729|AMERICAN DENTAL ASSOCIATION POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE|DI VINCENZO, GIORGIO T. DR.|1111 14TH STREET, NW|SUITE 1100|WASHINGTON|DC|200055627|B|Q|UNK|M|M|INDIANA DENTAL PAC|

When I run this code, all of the records come back "NaN."

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

print('convert CSV to dataframe')
data = pd.read_csv ('Desktop/Python/FECupdates/cm.txt', delimiter='|')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CMTE_ID','CMTE_NM','TRES_NM','CMTE_ST1','CMTE_ST2','CMTE_CITY','CMTE_ST','CMTE_ZIP','CMTE_DSGN','CMTE_TP','CMTE_PTY_AFFILIATION','CMTE_FILING_FREQ','ORG_TP','CONNECTED_ORG_NM','CAND_ID'])

print(df.head(10))
```

If I remove the dataframe part and just do this, it displays the data, so it doesn't seem like it's a problem with file itself (but what do I know?):

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
print('convert CSV to dataframe')
data = pd.read_csv ('Desktop/Python/FECupdates/cm.txt', delimiter='|')   
print(data.head(10))
```

I've spent hours looking at different questions here that seem to be trying to address similar issues -- in which cases the problems apparently stemmed from things like the encoding or different kinds of delimiters -- but each time I try to make the same changes to my code I get the same result. I've also converted the whole thing to a csv, by changing all the commas in fields to "$" and then changing the pipes to commas. It still shows up as all "Nan," even though the number of records is correct if I upload it to MySQL (they're just all empty).

Comment: After doing `data = pd.read_csv()`, `data` is already a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made typos in columns list. Pandas can automatically recognize columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

print('convert CSV to dataframe')
data = pd.read_csv ('cn.txt', delimiter='|')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.head(10))
```

Also, you can create an empty dataframe and concatenate the readed file.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

print('convert CSV to dataframe')
data = pd.read_csv ('cn.txt', delimiter='|')
data2 = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.concat([data,data2],ignore_index=True)
print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: Thank you @dasmehdix! That did it! I know it would be something simple like that. The data already doesn't have headers, so I added header=None and that allowed me to import the first line too. Worked like a charm. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

```
path = Desktop/Python/FECupdates
df = pd.read_csv(path+'cm.txt',encoding ='unicode_escape', sep='|')
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)

df.columns = ['CMTE_ID','CMTE_NM','TRES_NM','CMTE_ST1','CMTE_ST2','CMTE_CITY','CMTE_ST','CMTE_ZIP','CMTE_DSGN','CMTE_TP','CMTE_PTY_AFFILIATION','CMTE_FILING_FREQ','ORG_TP','CONNECTED_ORG_NM','CAND_ID']
df.head(200)
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBCWA.png)